# How to use forms authentication across applications when cookie paths don't match?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies, forms-authentication

I have three ASP.NET MVC applications. The first is a CMS that allows each user to have a customizable website. The second is the websites made with the first application. The last is an online store that is shared across all the customizable websites.

There are two types of users. The first can connect to the CMS to create his or her website. The second is the consumer of such website and of the shared online store.

For the sake of this question, let's say that the applications are available at the following addresses :

- www.example.com (for the CMS)
- www.example.com/website/userA (customized website for user A)
- www.example.com/website/userB (customized website for user B)
- store.example.com (for the online store)

To connect to the store, you need to have an account on a user's website and the store will take that user's colors and configuration when you connect.

At the moment, a user uses the same credentials to connect to the website and to the store. The applications use Forms Authentication. I would like for the connection to be available across applications so that when a user connects to the website, he or she is automatically connected to the store.

I have read a lot about how to setup Forms Authentication across applications, but I cannot seem to make this work because the two cookie paths are not the same. Indeed, the paths for the websites are '/website/userX' while the one for the store is '/'. I need the path to be set that way on the websites so that when a user logs in a website, he or she is not connected to all websites.

How could I make this work? Can I make the authentication work across both applications even if the paths are not the same or, if I change the path of the websites back to '/', is there another to ensure that when a user connects to one website, he or she is not connected to all websites?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

For the example you have give, you need to set the `domain`, on the forms authentication  config as:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms domain="example.com"  />
</authentication>
```

And with this set, the user can have the same authentication cookie on all the example site you have write. Then inside your side you need to check programmatically if the user have the writes to see it and work with it.